# Bash: Prepend variable from function to grep output

Tags: bash, perl

All, I use the following code to search for a term in the last lines of a logfile to send the error code (line found) when found. Since the line (error code) is not showing where it was found I added the OPERATION after this is performed as text.

```
if tail -5 *logfile* | grep '*term*'; then
tail -5 *logfile* | grep '*term*' |  perl -ne 'print "OPERATION: $_"' | sendxmpp ...
fi
```

But how can I transform this into a function with providing the OPERATION as a variable ($1)? Becaue I use this very often in a script.

```
#!/bin/sh
check_log () 
{
if tail -5 *logfile* | grep '*term*'; then
tail -5 *logfile* | grep '*term*' |  perl -ne 'print "$1: $_"' | sendxmpp ...
fi
}
check_log OPERATION
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below.  You can pass the shell variable (`$1`) to perl as a named variable (`prefix`) which you can then reference in your program.

```
#!/bin/sh
check_log () {
    if tail -5 *logfile* | grep '*term*'; then
        tail -5 *logfile* | grep '*term*' |  perl -sne 'print "$prefix: $_"' -- -prefix=$1 | sendxmpp ...
    fi
}
check_log OPERATION
```

Note that I have made 3 changes to your perl command:

1. The addition of `s` as an option.  This enables processing of switches after the program content.
2. The double-dash `--` terminates option processing. This tells Perl that what follows on the command line is *not* a Perl option.
3. `-prefix=$1` creates a Perl variable named `prefix`, who's value is the expanded value of the first argument passed to the function by the shell (`$1`).

Disclaimer - I am *not* a Perl expert.  There are probably other and better ways of doing this.  This is just an approach that I was able to make work.

Comment: Note that step 3 *only* defines a variable because of the `-s` option in step 1.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use spaces in this variable ($1 and $prefix)?

Comment: @MelBourbon Yes, you will probably need to send it through the shell like: `-prefix="$1"`

Comment: You can simply pass the variable as an [argument](https://perldoc.pl/variables/@ARGV) rather than an option, and avoid the need for any option parsing: `perl -ne 'print "$ARGV[0]: $_"' "$1" | ...`

Answer (score 0):

First, I suspect your `if` should use the `-q` flag on `grep`. (If it weren't for the pipe to sendxmpp, I wouldn't bother with the if, either.)

Second, I'm not sure about the regex you're passing in to grep, either. It seems fishy with the splats.

Third, I expect this is better done in sed:

```
tail -5 *logfile* | grep '...' | sed -e 's/^/'"$1"': /' | sendxmpp ...
```

Note that the same quoting trick can be used with perl as well.  The double-quotes may be superfluous if you never have spaces or such in the parameter.

(I would also classify this as a useless use of grep except that it's nice to use the same regex engine in both the `if` and the actual runtime.)